# Unable to remove line breaks in a text file in python

Tags: python, replace, strip

At the risk of losing reputation I did not know what else to do. My file is not showing any hidden characters and I have tried every .replace and .strip I can think of. My file is UTF-8 encoded and I am using python/3.6.1
I have a file with the format:

```
 >header1
 AAAAAAAA
 TTTTTTTT
 CCCCCCCC
 GGGGGGGG

 >header2
 CCCCCC
 TTTTTT
 GGGGGG
 AAAAAA
```

I am trying to remove line breaks from the end of the file to make each line a continuous string. (This file is actually thousands of lines long).
My code is redundant in the sense that I typed in everything I could think of to remove line breaks:

```
 fref = open(ref)
 for line in fref:
     sequence = 0
     header = 0
     if line.startswith('>'):
          header = ''.join(line.splitlines())
          print(header)
     else:
          sequence = line.strip("\n").strip("\r")
          sequence = line.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '').replace(' ', '').replace('\t', '')
          print(len(sequence))
```

output is:

```
 >header1
 8
 8
 8
 8
 >header2
 6
 6
 6
 6
```

But if I manually go in and delete the end of line to make it a continuous string it shows it as a congruent string.

Expected output:

```
 >header1
 32
 >header2
 24
```

Thanks in advance for any help,
Dennis

Comment: Could you show the output you expect?

Comment: well, you iterate over your file line by line with `for line in fref:` and in each iteration you print that one line (after some processing which does basically nothing). So of course you still get multiple lines as output, what did you expect?

Comment: @Guillaume I edited the question to reflect your input. Thanks!

Comment: `if line.startswith('>'): print('\n%s' % line.strip()); else:  print(line.strip(), end='')`.

Comment: You are successfully removing the line break from the end of each line. You should consider that maybe the problem you are trying to solve is a bit more involved than that. It seems as if you intend to `join` up the lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches to parsing this kind of input. In all cases, I would recommend isolating the **open** and **print** side-effects outside of a function that you can unit test to convince yourself of the proper behavior.

You could iterate over each line and handle the case of empty lines and end-of-file separately. Here, I use yield statements to return the values:

```
def parse(infile):
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith(">"):
            total = 0
            yield line.strip()
        elif not line.strip():
            yield total
        else:
            total += len(line.strip())
    if line.strip():
        yield total

def test_parse(func):
    with open("input.txt") as infile:
        assert list(parse(infile)) == [
            ">header1",
            32,
            ">header2",
            24,
        ]
```

Or, you could handle both empty lines and end-of-file at the same time. Here, I use an output array to which I append headers and totals:

```
def parse(infile):
    output = []
    while True:
        line = infile.readline()
        if line.startswith(">"):
            total = 0
            header = line.strip()
        elif line and line.strip():
            total += len(line.strip())
        else:
            output.append(header)
            output.append(total)
            if not line:
                break

    return output

def test_parse(func):
    with open("input.txt") as infile:
        assert parse(infile) == [
            ">header1",
            32,
            ">header2",
            24,
        ]
```

Or, you could also split the whole input file into empty-line-separated blocks and parse them independently. Here, I use an output stream to which I write the output; in production, you could pass the **sys.stdout** stream for example:

```
import re
def parse(infile, outfile):
    content = infile.read()
    for block in re.split(r"\r?\n\r?\n", content):
        header, *lines = re.split(r"\s+", block)
        total = sum(len(line) for line in lines)
        outfile.write("{header}\n{total}\n".format(
            header=header,
            total=total,
        ))

from io import StringIO
def test_parse(func): 
    with open("/tmp/a.txt") as infile: 
        outfile = StringIO() 
        parse(infile, outfile) 
        outfile.seek(0) 
        assert outfile.readlines() == [ 
            ">header1\n", 
            "32\n", 
            ">header2\n", 
            "24\n", 
        ]
```

Note that my tests use **open("input.txt")** for brevity but I would actually recommend passing a **StringIO(...)** instance instead to see the input being tested more easily, to avoid hitting the filesystem and to make the tests faster.

Comment: Thanks for the response, all your answers are returning the same results as peter posted below
`\n'`
`>header1'\n'` 
`>header2'\n'`
 `24`

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of your question you would like something like this:
Note how the sequence is build over multiple iteration steps of the loop, as you wish to combine multiple lines.

```
with open(ref) as f:
    sequence = "" # reset sequence
    header = None
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            if header:
                print(header)        # print last header
                print(len(sequence)) # print last sequence
            sequence = ""      # reset sequence
            header = line[1:]  # store header
        else:
            sequence += line.rstrip()   # append line to sequence
```

Comment: very close, but the output gives me:

>header

>header2

(length of sequence2)